# Authorising external Domains to embed my content

Tags: embed

I am looking for code to insert into a php file i.e. webfile.php (the content of this file is just basic html content), that will authorise/give selected domains the ability to embed this file. I was considering the external domains call the page via `<?php echo file_get_contents('webaddress/webfile.php'); ?>`

Comment: And what's your question about this? Is there anything not working?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a code service site. You need to show your code, what you have tried to solve the problem. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask